# How do you identify the target of a tap in Framer code overrides?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, overriding

This is a REACT newbie question, so bear with me. Documentation of Framer REACT code overrides isn't extensive. In the following Framer Prototype, I want to outline my choice of animal or world with a white border: https://structure-prevent-609548.framer.app/

The below code updates all the image borders, not just the one you click on. It's a hack of the Framer sample override file:

```
import type { ComponentType } from "react"
import { createStore } from "https://framer.com/m/framer/store.js@^1.0.0"
import { randomColor } from "https://framer.com/m/framer/utils.js@^0.9.0"

// Learn more: https://www.framer.com/docs/guides/overrides/

const useStore = createStore({
    border: "",
})

export function setBorder(Component): ComponentType {
    return (props) => {
        const [store, setStore] = useStore()

        return (
            <Component
                {...props}
                animate={{
                    border: store.border,
                }}
                onClick={() => {
                    {
                        store.border
                            ? setStore({
                                  border: "",
                              })
                            : setStore({
                                  border: "3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255)",
                              })
                    }
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I can't find a way to identify the target of the tap as in this.border, or something.

Comment: All images get a border when one image is clicked now but you want to give the border only for the image that is clicked. Is it your question?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @ArifurRahaman